# Split all characters in a string with no delimiter into an array with lotus notes

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

Im trying to split a sting variable into an array with each character in its own position in the array, but cant seem to get this to work

```
 function test() {
    var strString = "thisIsTheString";
    var test = @Explode(strString, "");
    var strReturn = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < @Length(test); i++) {
        strReturn += test[i] + "<br/>";
    }

    return strReturn;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `split` instead of `explode`?

Comment: You have tagged this question Lotusscript but your code snippet is not Lotusscript but rather server-side JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `split` function by passing empty string to it. For e.g.

```
var str = "this is a string";
var arr = str.split("");
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. That is the better answer of course. I guess I was too long with LotusScript... :)

Answer (score 3):

@Explode uses as delimiters space, comma and semicolon if second parameter is empty. That doesn't help you in your case. Just use "normal" string functions like `substring()`:

```
function test() {
    var strString = "thisIsTheString";
    var strReturn = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < strString.length; i++) {
        strReturn += strString.substring(i, i+1) + "<br/>";
    }

    return strReturn;
}
```

In case you really need an array of characters then code would look like this:

```
var strString = "thisIsTheString";
var arrayReturn = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < strString.length; i++) {
    arrayReturn[i] = strString.substring(i, i+1);
}
```